# Putnam Question Regarding Irrational Probability

Tags: probability

I came across the following problem and solution from a Putnam exam at this link: http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/problems-math/recpuz89

It states:

**Question**: If α is an irrational number, 0 < α < 1, is there a finite
game with an honest coin such that the probability of one player winning
the game is α? (An honest coin is one for which the probability of
heads and the probability of tails are both 1/2. A game is finite if
with probability 1 it must end in a finite number of moves.)

**Answer**: Yes. Write α in binary---there's no ambiguity since it's irrational.
At the nth step (n >= 0), flip the coin. If it comes up heads, go to the
next step. If it comes up tails, you win if the nth bit of α is 1.
Otherwise you lose. The probability of continuing forever is zero. The
probability of winning is α.

I wasn't sure I completely understood the game, so I decided to restate what I interpret to be the answer to see if I understood it correctly:

**A statement equivalent to the "game"?** Pick an n>=1 with probability distribution P(n)=(1/2)^(n). Look at the nth digit of the binary representation of an irrational number 0 < x < 1. The probability that this digit is 1 equals x.

Is the above equivalent to the game in the answer? If not, could you perhaps tell me where I fail in my attempt?

Thanks!

P.S.: Why would writing α in binary have ambiguity if α was rational?

*edit: Changed my statement to be 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed.*

Comment: To your P.S.: note that since $0.\overline{1}_2 = 1$, any terminating decimal can be substituted for one with a tail of repeating $1$s.

Comment: Please think twice about further edits. Each time you do it, any reader has to check that it has not signficantly changed. It is fine as it is.

Comment: Yes - sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this interesting question

Answer (score 0):

Your restatement looks fine to me. The chance that you get $n$ heads followed by a tail is obviously $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$. Of course, in your restatement you still have to check, having determined which binary digit of $x$ to examine, whether it is a 1.

More generally, that question (from Putnam 1989) was an easy question (by Putnam standards). It is a kind of updated version of the Zeno paradoxes. Probability is rife with events which can happen but have zero probability. They shouldn't puzzle us any more than infinite series of non-zero terms which nonetheless have a finite sum.